# Ошибка при работе с Flask : werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400

Tags: html, python, flask

Сама ошибка:

 
**werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'name'**

Попытался накидать по [примеру](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_http_methods.htm) аналогичный код.

`main.py:`

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/success/<username>')
def successfully_signed_in(username):
    return 'welcome, %s' % username

@app.route('/login',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def sing_in():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      user = request.form['name']
      return redirect(url_for('successfully_signed_in', username = user))
   else:
      user = request.args.get('name')
      return redirect(url_for('successfully_signed_in', username = user))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

`login.html :`

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "/login" method = "post">
         <p>Enter Name:</p>
         <p><input type = "text" name = "name" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

В изначальном примере атрибут `name = "nm"`, но если я меняю его на какое-либо другое имя,

то получаю эту ошибку, при том что и в `html` и в `python` коде эти имена совпадают,

как видно в примере приведенного мною кода в обоих местах это `name`.

Если меняю на `nm`, то все работает.


Вопрос первый - почему вызвано такое поведение?


Вопрос второй - почему `request.form` завязоно не на самом атрибуте, а на его значении, то есть `nm`, как в примере?

Comment: Покажите текст ошибки-то. И что значит «завязано ... на его значении»?

Comment: @andreymal, под завязано на его значении, я подразумевал, почему в случае, если атрибут `name ="atr_name"` мы получаем данные из запроса так: `user = request.form['atr_name']`, а не так `user = request.form['name']`. Вероятнее всего, ответ очевиден, но все же, буду Вам признателен, если укажите мне, что здесь не так, и что не так в моем понимани.

Comment: @LexMarchenko, сервер перезапускали после того как html изменили? Еще я попробовал бы выводить что реально через форму приходит.

Comment: @insolor, уже понял, что проблема была именно в том, что данные не обновлялись, сервер перезапускал, но только с определенной задержкой +- несколько минут в силу вступали некоторые изменения. В принципе я проблему свою решил, так что спасибо:) А касательно вывода, я пытался вставить в декоратор обычный принт, но я так понял, что он не срабатывает, почему мне не совсем понятно, но ладно)

Comment: @LexMarchenko, не в декторатор, в саму функцию можно print вставить, тогда в консоли сервера вывод отобразится.

Comment: @LexMarchenko дайте угадаю, вы после перезапуска сервера просто забыли страницу в браузере обновить?